# How to display Decimal and Date Arrays from MySQL database using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, numeric

I am having difficulty getting Price and Date to display on the webpage.

Below is a section of the current code that I have. The MYSQLI_ASSOC part displays the correct data but the MYSQLI_NUM section of the code does not display at all. I am having trouble finding information on how to make it work.

```
 <?php
    $query = "SELECT ItemID, Name, Category, Price, Duration, Photo FROM 
    item ORDER by ItemID LIMIT 3";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
         echo "<br> Row: ". $row["ItemID"]. " - Name: ". $row["Name"]. "<br> " . $row["Category"] .  "<br>" ;
   }
    } else {
      echo "0 results";
  }

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
       echo "<br> Price: ". $row["Price"]. " - Finish Time: ". $row["Duration"]. "<br> ";
   }
    } else {
      echo "0 results";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MYSQLI_NUM is the 'ordinal position' of a column, starting with 0 to the first column in the query results, 1 for the next column, 2 for the next, and so on. For example, if the 'Price' column appears first in the query results, it will be `$row[0]`, but in your query, it is currently at `$row[3]`. Otherwise, use the number that corresponds to the correct position of the query for the column.

See this for an example:  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Also, know that because your first loop cycles the recordset before your 2nd loop, you'll need to reset the list to avoid having to query twice.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 // output data of each row
 $result->data_seek(0); // set the recordset back to the first row.

 while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
```

MYSQLI_BOTH, which is the default, returns an array so that you can use the row results by column name OR by column number.

======

Know that many don't like using the column order numbers except for very small queries, like ones that return a single row, typically having only one column, such a count query. The reason is that if a larger query ever changes the column ordering, then the code has be 'scoured' to ensure that the column position numbers align/match to the updated query changes.

Comment: Awesome thanks for your help. I added the code together